# OpenOffice: Replace text with new-line

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice

In my OpenOffice spreadsheet, there are cells containing "\n" text.

Each "\n" occurrence needs to be replaced with a new line or line break.

The Find-and-Replace dialog does offer regular expressions when searching. So I can find them using \n but when the replacement is set to \n it replaces the occurrence with the text "\n" instead of a new line.

How can one Find-and-Replace a text into a new line?

Comment: you want every cell after each cell with `/n` to drop down a row? Or do you want line breaks within the cells?

Comment: The cells themselves must not shift down. I want line breaks within the cells. Those cells contain text that needs those line breaks

Comment: In the other options for Find and replace choose Regular Expression and set replace with as \n.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find and replace` to find `/n` and replace with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Remember if you have a space after your `/n` that you include that space in the find-and-replace otherwise the new lines will start with a space

Comment: Doesn't work. Typing alt+0013 get's interpreted as pressing Enter in the search and replace dialog, so it just jumps the cursor to the first instance.

Comment: Where are you having this issue? Are you using the right number pad? Are you on Windows? etc

Comment: Yes to both. Windows 7.

Comment: Oh, I'm using LibreOffice, sorry. Maybe that is the difference.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It just replaces with "nothing".

Comment: Still doesn't work. Are you just guessing or have you actually tested this out?

Comment: You are testing in Excel?! Come on. Obviously these programs behave differently. Good to know though, I do have Excel Starter edition, so I could use that in the future.

Comment: Why would they behave differently? [Line Feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed) is universal. If you're really having a problem, I suggest you propose a new question so it has more visibility

Comment: It doesn't matter how "universal" anything is. Obviously Calc is handling alt+0013 as an actual press of the enter key and it just ignores the alt+0010, either when you attempt to enter it in the replace box, or it is ignoring carriage returns without also having the linefeed, whereas Excel interprets those codes as characters and probably adds its own linefeed when you attempt to insert a carriage return without one.

Comment: [check here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Inserting_Line_Breaks_in_Cells)

Comment: That doesn't have a solution for search and replace. I already read that. Don't worry about this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To search a character string XXX followed by a new-line, and replace it with the character string YYY followed by a new-line:

- type the character string XXX immediately followed by the 2 characters alt+0013 and alt+0010 in the search box,
- and type the character string YYY immediately followed by the 2 characters alt+0013 and alt+0010 in the replace box